# Nautilus Git integration

Tags: software-recommendation, nautilus, git, rabbitvcs

Is there any equivalent to TortoiseSVN but for Ubuntu / Git? I'd like to integrate Git commands to Nautilus.

Comment: I have installed RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 11.10 via sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3 But how do I run it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) integrates Git into Nautilus. It is available for Ubuntu from a PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

For 11.04 and earlier:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

For 11.10 and later:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3
```

You should reload Nautilus after!

Comment: the package's now called `rabbitvcs-nautilus`

Comment: It's very, very slow on my computer.

Comment: RabbitVCS does not work with Nautilus 3.8, the version shipped with Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: This software just plain sucks. There's no more polite way I can put it. I considered fixing it, but [it can't be done](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_can%27t_polish_a_turd).

Answer (score 15):

This has been proposed already on [Ubuntu braninstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/10420/) and on [GNOME-Look.org](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Nautilus+VCS+Integration?content=126126) but no code seems to be available at the moment.

There is however a GNOME GUI front-end for Git called [Giggle](http://live.gnome.org/giggle) which is available in the Ubuntu 10.04 repositories (pre-packaged for other distributions as well, see the [web page](http://live.gnome.org/giggle)): `apt-get install giggle`.

Comment: But does Giggle do nautilus integration? I didn't see how.

Comment: It doesn't. And Giggle is broken. [Gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg) is better, but it also doesn't integrate with Nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any Nautilus extensions for git. There is a [set of nautilus scripts](http://github.com/tapio/nautilus-git-scripts) but that isn't quite the same as the integration you get with [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) for svn or [bzr-gtk](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr-gtk) for bzr.

Comment: https://github.com/tapio/nautilus-git-scripts.git is a quite nice. Thanks for the pointer. It fails to handle multiple files for rename/delete, but that's a very good start.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://github.com/bil-elmoussaoui/nautilus-git/
Works with both Nautilus & Nemo on Gtk3.14+
[image]

Not perfect, does not implement a lot of things but help/ideas are welcome!