# Automatically mark files and directories tracked by git in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, git

When you use git for a lot of projects it can sometimes be hard to remember which projects you use git for and which you don't. It's important to know this so that you commit changes if you make changes to projects tracked by git.

Is there a way to automatically mark files and directories tracked by git so that they show in Nautilus, e.g. by marking them with emblems?

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4788/nautilus-git-integration) suggests that [RabbitVCS](http://www.rabbitvcs.org/) does what you want. I went to their website and indeed the screenshots suggest it adds some icons to git-conrolled directories:

[image: RabbitVCS screenshot]

Comment: On http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/about it says "Currently, it is integrated into the Nautilus file manager and *only supports Subversion*, but our goal is to incorporate other version control systems as well as other file managers." (my emphasis).

Comment: Well, that page is definitely obsolete - you can find Git-related code in the source code - http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/source/browse/trunk/rabbitvcs/vcs/git/__init__.py; also, I installed it and can confirm that it does indeed support both git and svn.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm afraid I cannot get it to work with git though. I get ". is not a working copy" when I try to browse a repository and there's no emblems showing.

Comment: Could this be the difference between installing the latest from source vs installing what is currently in the apt repos?

Comment: I didn't install from source - I followed their normal installation instructions - added the ppa; apt-get update; apt-get install. Ubuntu 11.04.