# tortoisegit for ubuntu

Tags: unity, gnome, software-recommendation, nautilus, git

Are there any alternatives to ToroiseGIT for Ubuntu?

I'm looking for something to integrate GIT with nautilus in the context menu.

Like TortoiseHG used to (replaced with [HG scripts](https://bitbucket.org/zeitue/nautilus-mercurial-scripts))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nautilus Git integration](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4788/nautilus-git-integration)

Comment: For XUbuntu users (and not only) Thunar have the great [thunar-vcs-plugin](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/thunar-vcs-plugin)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest rabbitvcs, which supports nautilus integration for SVN and GIT:

[rabbitvcs website](http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/install/ubuntu)

Comment: +1 If you like the way tortoise works, you'll love rabbitvcs. Also there is a rabbitvcs plug-in to gedit so you can manage your versioning without leaving the editor.

Comment: Sounds cool I'll check it out. it would have been a bonus if it supported mercurial also.

Comment: How do I right click a file and commit it with rabbitvcs?

Comment: It looks like they aren't maintaining binary releases anymore, so it's become much harder for new users to install this on Bionic and above.

Comment: RabbitVCS has a serious bug of not being able to commit the deletion of files. I had this issue too. (https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/issues/308)

Answer (score 4):

SmartGit is fabulous - http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/

I've used Tortoise and for Git the SmartGit makes it that simple to use.

Comment: It isn't free but has 30-days trial.

Comment: I used both. SmartGit lacks important functions for managing large repositories, eg. filter commits, only show commits with tag/branch, etc.