# How to tag folders in Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus, tagging

I need to manage all my Git repositories tagging them in order to be able to check for tag-related projects afterwards.
Is there any solution integrated with Nautilus?

Comment: What do you mean by tagging? Something like in [macOS Finder](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202754), [git tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), or something different?

Comment: Something like in macOS Finder. To be able to tag folders (of repositories I have cloned in my pc) and then search for them using tags from Nautilus

Answer (score 0):

RabbitVCS integrates Git into Nautilus. It is available for Ubuntu from a PPA.

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/14529/42348

Maybe this helps you. I have not tried to up to now.